# get the value in override method using object oriented

Tags: java, oop

here is the class that extends CountDownTimer.

```
public class timer extends CountDownTimer{

private final long startTime = 50000;
private final long interval = 1000;
int timeElapsed;

public timer(long starttime, long interval){
    super(starttime, interval);     
}

@Override
public void onFinish() {        

}

@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    timeElapsed = (int)(startTime - millisUntilFinished);       
}
```

}

here is the main class.

```
long millisUntilFinished = 0;
        timer myTime = new timer(5000, 1000);
        myTime.onTick(millisUntilFinished);

        if(myTime.onTick(millisUntilFinished) == 2000){
            //do the next process
        }
```

This code tells

> the operator == is undefined for thee type(s) void, int

how i want to get the value timeElapsed that is in the override method and the value can be used in the main class for the next process.

please help me to resolve this. thanks for advance.

Comment: `myTime.onTick` is a **void** method. You can't use it to assign a value because it returns nothing. Create a getter for your property.

Comment: FFS start class names with capital letters!

Comment: @Luiggi: he's not assigning a value to it, but he *is* trying to compare void with int using the `==` operator which is just as illegal.

Comment: @sarah: when posting questions like this, don't paraphrase the error message because you're leaving out important information. Instead post the entire error message.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I agree, it's just a bad habit of me thinking that the return value is assigned `on the fly` before being used in the comparison inside the `if`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i copied all the error. even im using setter getter in the timer class, and in the main i do mytime.gettime it still give a null value.

Comment: @Sara: thanks for the correction. Your error message tells you *exactly* what you're doing wrong. Solution: don't do this. Only compare values that make sense to compare.

Answer (score 1):

The `void` return type means that no value is returned by the method, so a compiler error occurs when you attempt to compare a void value with `2000`.

The best solution here is to simply create a getter method to access `timeElapsed` and then use that method in the equality comparison.

```
public class timer extends CountdownTimer {
    ...
    public int getTimeElapsed() {
        return timeElapsed;
    }
    ...
}
```

Then, in your main method, you can use that getter method.

```
...
if (myTime.getTimeElapsed() == 2000) {
    // do the next process
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method call `myTime.onTick(millisUntilFinished)` doesn't return anything hence the error.

I think you are trying to compare against `timeElapsed` which you can do as below.

Add a method `getTimeElapsed()` in `timer` class as:

```
   public int getTimeElapsed(){
      return timeElapsed;
   }
```

Then in you main method, you can do like:

```
    long millisUntilFinished = 0;
    timer myTime = new timer(5000, 1000);
    myTime.onTick(millisUntilFinished);

    if(myTime.getTimeElapsed() == 2000){
        //do the next process
    }
```

Comment: if im doing this, i would return null value, am i correct? the timeElapsed will be taken from the override method.

Comment: @sarabrown return null from `onTick()` method? If so, your if condition will not be satisfied. I think better to return the `timeElapsed` from `onTick()` method or expose it through a new method. Please Note: If you plan to add the return type in `onTick()` method, please change that in super class as well.

Comment: im not really into oop, please help me to figure this out. what i should put in the super method? or perhaps i should not use the super method at all? next question is im extending the CountDownTimer which is already java object, i think which need me to override onTick method. does this effecting what im trying to do; getting the value from the override method?

Comment: @sarabrown One step at a time. `@override` annotation means `onTick` method exist in the super class `CountDownTimer` as well and you are overriding its implementation in the subclass. The method signature in both super and sub class should match. Hence I said, If you want to add return type, update both the class methods. If your `CountDownTimer` is one from android i.e. `android.os.CountDownTimer` then you can modify that class. In that case you have two options. Either use a new method as I mentioned in my answer to get the `timeElapsed` or have a new method `onTick` without overriding.

Comment: im sorry, can you explain it by coding? i still dont get it on have new method without override. i need to modified the super first, but how. i mean if im not override the method, can the CountDownTimer can be used?